# Continuity in a physical context

Tags: analysis, continuity, physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm currently trying to solve an exercise for my quantum mechanics class and have run into a bit of a jam:

Suppose we have the following potential :

$V(x) = 0$ if $x > |a/2|$ but $V(x) = V_0$ if $x < |a/2|$.

The Schrödinger equation is the following: $-\hbar^2 / 2m \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \psi = (E-V(x))\psi$. The ansatz for the three regions are simply a superposition of incoming and reflected plane waves, i.e. $\psi_i(x) = A_iexp(-kx) + B_iexp(kx)$.

One can easily check that this solution solves the Schrödinger equation in all three regions. 
My question is now the following:

In the solution to this exercise we integrate the Schrödinger equation over a small region around the edges of the three regions, i.e.:

$\psi'(x_0 + \epsilon) - \psi'(x_0 - \epsilon) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} (-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \int_{x_0 - \epsilon}^{x_0 + \epsilon} (E-V(x))\psi)$

The sample solution now immediately concluded, that the right side is zero, and therefore both the derivative and thus the function itself are continuous.

I asked an assistant and he told me "it is enough to know that both the potential and the wave function are bounded to show that the right hand side is zero".

Can someone explain to me how exactly that is enough? I mean if $\psi$ were a function without continuity then there could be a jump between $x_0 + \epsilon$ and $x_0 - \epsilon$ and the integral wouldn't vanish?

Hope someone can shed some light on this for me!

Cheers.

Comment: The rhs you're talking about is the *limit* of the integral as $\epsilon\to 0$. Of course, if $(E-V(x))\psi$ is bounded by $B$, so $|(E-V(x)\psi|<B$, then the integral is bounded by $2\epsilon B$. Take the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ and you get... $0$.

Comment: Well if you put it like this its obvious... how does this hold up with a Heaviside function though? The rhs is the definition of continuity, right? The Heaviside function isn't continuous but is still bounded from above, so your argumentation would still hold. Whats wrong with my thought process?

Comment: In physics, everything is approximation, including the mathematics and mathematical model using. Physically, a step function like this should be viewed as the limit of a very steep slope. If you compute the $\psi'(x_0+\epsilon)-\psi'(x_0-\epsilon)$ for a potential well with very steep slope, take the limit of the slope first and then the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$, you will get zero. ie. $\psi'(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. Don't mistaken definition you learn in a math course with the actual limiting/approximation procedure one used to define quantities in physics.

Comment: What the TA said is correct (obviously). But he was just talking about the integral limit, which doesn't show much at all. (1) Just because $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} f(x+\epsilon) - f(x-\epsilon)=0$ does *not* mean $f$ is continuous at $x$. Stare at the definition of continuity. One of those terms needs to be $f(x)$ to prove continuity. (2) The last equation you wrote is wrong: the lhs depends on $\epsilon$, the rhs does not. (You may need a $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}$ on the lhs.) (3) This looks like a "physicists' proof", i.e., maybe there's something to it, but it's imprecise.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just assume $\psi$ is smooth (at least has first and second derivatives) until you can't make that assumption work. For example, the momentum and Hamiltonian operators assume first and second differentiability of $\psi$, respectively. Physicists are very often sloppy in their arguments compared to mathematicians. This is a source of endless frustration, but if one can get passed the sloppiness, there's obviously a lot of power in what they do!